# Why running 1 user load test giving strange results while 50 users are running with normal results

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, loadrunner, rpt

I ran two performance tests using IBM rational performance tester(RPT) on my application. My application is a j2ee application running on a weblogic server.

**First RPT schedule (baseline test):**  1 User (set to until finished) with 10 iterations.

**Second schedule:** 50 Users for 6 hrs.

I ran this on production application on the weekends when there is very less real users load.

**Issue:** The RPT report for baseline test shows lot of **spikes** in various report graphs and result seems to have abnormal behaviour.

My recorded test script also includes a login page which virtual user use to logged in.

While checking the log analysis of a monitoring tool (my company specific one), it was found that there was near about 8 or 10 minutes’ gap between login requests of virtual user.

The *timeout* value in *Http Options* tab in *test elements details* of a recorded test window is set to 240000 milliseconds.

The RPT graph results for this single user appear abnormal.

I have attached pics of RPT reports graphs for baseline schedule.(pics started with ‘*baseline_*’ prefix).

While in the report graphs of **50 users** test schedule (ran for 6 hours) it was found that there were no strange spikes and results appear to have normal behavior.

I have attached pics of RPT reports graphs for 50 users(for 6 hrs) schedule.(pics started with *’50 users 6 hrs_*’ prefix).

FYI: Both schedules ran on productions system when real user load is similar in both cases and is very less.

I even ran 100 users for 2 hrs later. They also ran fine and RPT report graphs appeared giving normal results/behavior. Even I ran 250 users. They also ran fine giving normal behavior of application in RPT result reports.

**Can anybody tell me why the running only one user( with 10 iteration loop) giving strange results while running 50 users(for 6 hrs) gave normal results?**

**Baseline schedule run RPT reports:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**50 User schedule run RPT reports:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]